# How to preload a font with with Webpack Encore and webfonts-loader?

Tags: webfonts, preload, webpack-encore

My project is built on :

- Symfony / Webpack Encore bundle
- [webfonts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfonts-loader)

Running a Lighthouse audit, the first opportunity to improve performances is :

> Consider using `<link rel=preload>` to prioritize fetching resources
>   that are currently requested later in page load
>   ...fonts/app.icons.e5d7e11....woff

How can I automatically insert Link tag with rel="preload" to this file ?

Answer (score 5):

If you can use the latest Webpack Encore, this is directly supported via webpack_encore.yaml, simply set `preload:true` under the `webpack_encore:` key. You can use the standard helper methods in this case.

Example:

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('my_entry_point') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('my_entry_point') }}
```

Source: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle

However, if you have an older version of Encore, you will need to install web-link `composer require symfony/web-link` as suggested in another answer, and manually iterate the webpack files using the encore file helpers, instead of the typical encore tag helpers.

Example:

```
{% for file in encore_entry_css_files('my_entry_point') %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ preload(asset(file), {as: 'style'}) }}">
{% endfor %}

{% for file in encore_entry_js_files('my_entry_point') %}
     <script src="{{ preload(asset(file), {as: 'script'}) }}"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Encore bundle automatically installs and configures the Asset component (if using Symfony Flex), after which you can use `asset()` to retrieve the versioned fonts file.

Assuming that you configured Webpack Encore to generate files to `public/build/`:

```html
// In base.html.twig <head>:
<link rel="preload" href="{{ asset('build/fonts/some-font.woff2') }}" as="font" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
```

This will result in the following tag being rendered:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/build/fonts/some-font.6f75f467.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Internally, `asset()` uses the manifest.json that Webpack generates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preload twig function from the symfony/web-link package.
First, install the package with

```
composer require symfony/web-link
```

then, in your code, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ preload('/app.css', { as: 'style' }) }}">
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/web_link.html

Comment: How would you preload '...fonts/app.icons.e5d7e11....woff' (from your question)? The `parts` comes from webpack so you can't just use 'app.icons.woff'.